# Need to send a single attribute from Json file as input to a http request

Tags: jmeter

I have decoded a response using beanshell script and saved it in a XML file.

**Beanshell Post Processor script**

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

String response= vars.get("data");
vars.put("response",new String(Base64.decodeBase64(response)));

Output = vars.get("response");

f = new FileOutputStream("E:/JMeter/apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/response.xml");
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(Output);
f.close();
```

**Response**

```
{
  "Username": "raghuram.k@cafyne.com",
  "UserCreateDate": "2017-02-23T04:02:59.123Z",
  "UserLastModifiedDate": "2017-02-23T04:04:50.695Z",
  "Enabled": true,
  "UserStatus": "CONFIRMED",
  "sub": "50e0dff7-0342-40f1-b793-68de404d95c4",
  "_app": "586cc7cc851dc874ac59f001",
  "email_verified": "true",
  "_org": "58adbaf2ffc4de735f1fbe28",
  "name": "Raghu Ram kota",
  "_groups": [
    {
      "_id": "58adbaf2ffc4de735f1fbe29",
      "name": "default",
      "slug": "default",
      "description": "Default Group",
      "id": "58adbaf2ffc4de735f1fbe29"
    }
  ],
  "_roles": [
    {
      "_id": "58adbaf2ffc4de735f1fbe2a",
      "name": "ADMIN",
      "slug": "admin",
      "description": "ADMIN Role",
      "id": "58adbaf2ffc4de735f1fbe2a"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": {
    "listen": {
      "DELETE": false,
      "READ": true,
      "UPDATE": false,
      "CREATE": false
    },
    "profile": {
      "STOPLISTEN": true,
      "STARTLISTEN": true,
      "AUTHORIZE": true,
      "DELETE": true,
      "READ": true,
      "UPDATE": true,
      "CREATE": true
    },
    "post": {
      "DELETE": true,
      "READ": true,
      "UPDATE": true,
      "CREATE": true
    },
    "group": {
      "DELETE": true,
      "READ": true,
      "UPDATE": true,
      "CREATE": true
    },
    "user": {
      "DELETE": true,
      "READ": true,
      "UPDATE": true,
      "CREATE": true
    }
  },
  "email": "raghuram.k@cafyne.com",
  "meta": {},
  "isAdmin": "false",
  "iat": 1487919175,
  "exp": 1487926375
}
```

**Now I need to send only the _org value, Which is highlighted, as input to another http request. Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend switching to [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language as:

- Groovy has built-in [Base64 encoding/decoding support](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.0/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/EncodingGroovyMethods.html)
- Groovy has built-in [JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- Groovy is more Java-compliant
- Groovy performs much better than Beanshell

So you can get your `_org` value as simple as:

```
def response = vars.get("data")

def decodedResponse = new String(response.decodeBase64())

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(decodedResponse)

log.info(json._org)
```

[image: JSON Groovy Base64 JMeter]

See [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more comprehensive information.

Comment: Thank you but how can we send this as input to another http request. I replaced log.info(json_org) with vars.put("CompId", json_org) and used it in another hhtp request as ${CompId}. Am I missing anything.

Comment: Just store it into a JMeter Variable like `vars.put("org", json._org)` and refer as `${org}` later on where required